# StringDictionary not saving as user setting

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a user scoped setting with the type "System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary".  Whenever I open the local settings, I can see it in the config, but it's empty.

I have other user settings that save correctly, but this dictionary doesn't seem to be saving at all.

Is there something I need to do in order to get a dictionary to save?

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that the `Dictionary` doesn't serialize to XML (even though it really should). You have two options. You can specify your own serialization methods for the dictionary, or you can cheat.

If you don't care about being able to read/edit the values in the XML, you can add a `[SettingSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]` attribute to the setting. Gets the job done, but it's the quick-and-dirty approach.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling Save().  All my other settings are saving correctly except my StringDictionary.

Comment: For a serializable string dictionary see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6194818/492336

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about any specific issues or workarounds for working with `StringDictionary` in the settings, but perhaps side-step the issue and just work with a string? You could serialize the data as xml, or (perhaps simpler) just a key/value delimited string? Note that `DbConnectionStringBuilder` offers a simple way of doing this (as below).

The tokenized string is "abc=def;ghi=jkl", but it will automatically handle escaping rules etc for more complex data. Worth a try?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data.Common;
public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringDictionary lookup = new StringDictionary();
        lookup.Add("abc", "def");
        lookup.Add("ghi", "jkl");

        string foo = Serialize(lookup);
        Console.WriteLine(foo);

        StringDictionary bar = Deserialize(foo);
        foreach (string key in bar.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", key, bar[key]);
        }
    }
    public static string Serialize(StringDictionary data)
    {
        if(data == null) return null; // GIGO
        DbConnectionStringBuilder db = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in data.Keys)
        {
            db[key] = data[key];
        }
        return db.ConnectionString;
    }
    public static StringDictionary Deserialize(string data)
    {
        if (data == null) return null; // GIGO
        DbConnectionStringBuilder db = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        StringDictionary lookup = new StringDictionary();
        db.ConnectionString = data;
        foreach (string key in db.Keys)
        {
            lookup[key] = Convert.ToString(db[key]);
        }
        return lookup;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a horrible abuse of DbConnectionStringBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary is not saved because there is no implement XmlSerializable.
I'm not sure but it seems to me.