# Change multiple, similarly named variable values at the same time

Tags: c#

First time on stackOverflow, so this might be a really nooby question, but i was wondering if i could change multiple variable values at the same time without having to write out every single one.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
public string Label1Text()
{
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < 32; index++)
    {
        if (seatChosen[index])
        {
            _bookedSeats += "A" + (index + 1) + " ";
            Properties.Settings.Default.A1 = true;
        }
    }

    string text = _bookedSeats + ".";

    //debug
    label1.Text = text;

    return text;
}
```

The line

```
Properties.Settings.Default.A1 = true;
```

is what i want to change to something like this (theoretical code)

```
Properties.Settings.Default.A[index] = true;
```

or

```
Properties.Settings.Default.A + index = true;
```

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't.

Comment: Less simple answer: You could use reflection, but it's probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: In your case, you could switch to an actual dictionary in your settings as discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922047/store-dictionarystring-string-in-application-settings

Comment: Check this post , you can use `Dictionary` instead.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: It seems like you are coding this in an odd way. Why are you defining all of the `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, etc, variables in the first place? Why not use an array?

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection:  (I'm assuming Properties.Settings.Default is a static class, and A1, A2, etc. are public static properties.)

```
Type type = typeof(Properties.Settings.Default);
var prop = type.GetProperty(index.ToString("\\A0"));
if (prop != null)
    prop.SetValue(null, true);
```

If Default is an instance, you would need to pass it to SetValue instead of null.  Also, C# v6 allows a more concise syntax.

```
Type type = Properties.Settings.Default.GetType();
type.GetProperty($"A{index}")?.SetValue(Properties.Settings.Default, true);
```

Comment: While this does answer the question, I wouldn't recommend this approach unless you are dealing with properties that are unknown at compile time. IMHO, this a warning that the structure of your code needs to be looked at. I certainly wouldn't want to see any of my team using something as heavy as reflection just to save manually typing a few extra lines.