# Saving Dictionary into My.Settings doesn't work

Tags: dictionary, my.settings, stringdictionary

I am trying to save `Dictionary(Of String, String)` into `My.Settings`. It seems, that those settings only support `System.Collection.Speciallized.StringDictionary`, which is not exactly the same thing, but would be OK. I create a `StringDictionary`, fill it with a test data and try to save it, but it doesn't get saved. While another property `CacheUpdateDate` of type `Date` is saved fine, created or updated as needed. The scope of the properties is "user".

[image]

```
                Dim StrDict As New System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary
                For Each xmlf As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In XMLfilesCache
                    StrDict.Add(xmlf.Key, xmlf.Value)
                Next
                Console.WriteLine("StrDict contains " & StrDict.Count.ToString & " files.")

                My.Settings.XMLcache = StrDict
                My.Settings.CacheUpdateDate = Date.Now
                My.Settings.Save()
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <DocServiceMonitor.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="CacheUpdateDate" serializeAs="String">
                <value>05/15/2023 11:26:44</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="XMLcache" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </DocServiceMonitor.My.MySettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Problem as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194818/7034621) is that `StringDictionary` does not implement `IXmlSerializable`.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I missed that thread although I did quite in-depth search on SO and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are several problems with using the `StringDictionary` in `My.Settings` and furthermore, I could see several advices against using this old type.

So my solution was to avoid `My.Settings` and simply save it to a dedicated text ("cache") file as an array of lines with `|` separator.