# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Application user settings)

Tags: c#, .net, null, settings

In my user settings for the application, I have a `StringDictionary` named "websites". A NullReferenceException with the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when it reaches this line: `Properties.Settings.Default.websites.Add(nameBox.Text, urlBox.Text);`, but I can't figure out why. The VS debugger shows that nameBox.Text and urlBox.Text are the right values.

**Edit:**

I've determined that it's null by default, so on Form.Load, I added

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.websites == null) {
            MessageBox.Show("property is null");
            Properties.Settings.Default.websites = new StringDictionary();
}
```

but now the settings aren't saving.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Is any part of Properties.Settings.Default.websites null?

Comment: @JohnSaunders this question is not duplicate to the one you pointed out because it is specifically about Properties.Settings

Comment: @HatSoft: it is very certainly a duplicate. It's another case of, "you expected a reference to refer to something, but, surprise, it doesn't".

Comment: possibly related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424010/stringdictionary-not-saving-as-user-setting

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your StringDictionary  websites Scope is set to Application which cannot be modified at runtime. You will have change the scope to user so it can be changed at runtime  per user

> **Taken from MSDN**
>
> [Application-scoped settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) can be used for information such as a URL
>   for a Web service or a database connection string. These values are
>   associated with the application. Therefore, users cannot change them
>   at run time.

**Edit:** To save the settings you will have to use `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: @airplaneman19 in that case can u check that nameBox.Text, urlBox.Text are not null when using websites.Add

Comment: Yeah, the debugger shows that they have valid values. Please see my edit.

Comment: I added that to my code, but it's still null when I reopen the application.

Comment: @airplaneman19 you are setting a new of StringDictionaty instance on form_load that cleans up the previous one the one that u saved

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14309/discussion-between-hatsoft-and-airplaneman19)