# Serialize DbConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, odbc, oledb

How do I serialize [DbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) object. I need to send the object from server to client.

Tried serializing the IDcitionary using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam/archive/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c.aspx) approach. But On client side, when I add those keys to object it assigns a funky connection string to it. And if you do

```
_connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString = string.Empty;
```

That removes all the keys.

**is it possible to return DbProviderFactory object from server to client ?**

Comment: Why not just send the connection string instead?  You can only serialize data anyway, not methods.

Answer (score 1):

"[StringDictionary not saving as user setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424010/stringdictionary-not-saving-as-user-setting)" shows a way of serializing `DbConnectionString`:

```
public static string Serialize(StringDictionary data)
{
    if(data == null) return null; // GIGO
    DbConnectionStringBuilder db = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
    foreach (string key in data.Keys)
    {
        db[key] = data[key];
    }
    return db.ConnectionString;
}
public static StringDictionary Deserialize(string data)
{
    if (data == null) return null; // GIGO
    DbConnectionStringBuilder db = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
    StringDictionary lookup = new StringDictionary();
    db.ConnectionString = data;
    foreach (string key in db.Keys)
    {
        lookup[key] = Convert.ToString(db[key]);
    }
    return lookup;
}
```

The `StringDictionary` would be used for serialization.

Comment: I get your approach, but first time when I dont have connection string. I create this DbConnectionStringBuilder  on server and return its keys. The moment I assign them to DbConnectionStringBuilder object on client it creates a funky connection string using those key-values. While I expect it to be empty before user actually adds a connection string on form.

Comment: @buffer_overflow I'm not sure I follow--you're creating `DbConnectionStringBuilder` object and assigning keys to it and expecting it to be "empty" (i.e. no keys)?

Comment: DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName); 
            Debug.Assert(factory != null);
            DbConnectionStringBuilder _connectionStringBuilder = factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder(); Here _connectionStringBuilder  has key-values but connectionstring is empty. Now I serialize this dict and send it back to client. On assigning this values to client _connectionStringBuilder  object, it auto generates a connection string which is weird.

Comment: Ahh, okay.  When you create the `DbConnectionStringBuilder` that way, it instantiates a specific type of DbConnectionStringBuilder (like `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` which will have a read-only `Keys` collection specific to that provider.  The values have not been set.  The values are set/retrieved through the class indexer (like `_connectionStringBuilder["Application Name"] = "my application";`

Comment: Or is it possible to return DbProviderFactory object from server to client ?

Comment: The example code shows how to deserialize a StringDictionary into a DbConnectionStringBuilder.  It's the values you want, the Keys are read-only and are only the names of the keys that you can assign values to.